# How can I determine which reference I'm missing in this Outlook interop code (OlItemType.olMailItem)?

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, com-interop

I'm using my Interop Outlook code, which required me to add a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook ("Microsoft Outlook 12.0 Object Library"; Version = 9.3.0.0)

Adding that reference caused all the redded up Outlook classes to resolve to more subdued hues, but attempting to build the project still causes a compiler error, namely, "*One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?*"

The code is this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
MailItem mailItem = app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
mailItem.Subject = String.Format("Platypus file generated {0}", GetYYYYMMDDHHMM());
mailItem.To = emailAddr;
```

When I 2-click that err msg, this is highlighted:

```
app.CreateItem(OlItemType.olMailItem);
```

Here's an even odder one:

```
"*Predefined type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Binder' is not defined or imported*"
```

2-clicking it leads nowhere; maybe it will go away once I appease the first beast.

What additional reference do I need to add to get this to compile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Microsoft.CSharp` must be referenced.  It should be one of the available framework assemblies.